# Correlation ID in multi-threaded and multi-process application

Tags: multithreading, logging

I've joined a legacy project, where there's virtually no logging. Few days ago we had a production release that failed massively, and we had no clear idea what's going on. That's why improving logging is one of the priorities now.

I'd like to introduce something like "correlation id", but I'm not sure what approach to take. Googling almost always brings me to the solutions that are suitable for "Microservices talking via REST" architecture, which is not my case.

Architecture is a mix of Spring Framework and NodeJS running on the same Unix box - it looks like this:

1. Spring receives a Request (first thread is started) and does minor processing.
2. Processing goes to a thread from ThreadPool (second thread is started).
3. Mentioned second thread starts a separate process of NodeJS that does some HTML processing.
4. Process ends, second thread ends, first thread ends.

Options that come to my mind are:

1. Generate UUID and pass it around as argument.
2. Generate UUID and store it in ThreadLocal, pass it when necessary when changing threads or when starting a process.

Any other ideas how it can be done correctly?

Comment: Human can memorize 7 digits, something that telephone companies know well.  A uuid is easy to generate but very painful to read back, consider an int that starts counting at 1.  You only have to make sure you increment it in a thread-safe way.

Comment: Hi Hans. I think problems of implementing distributed counter outweighs the benefits of having a "human readable" correlation id. Ultimately, I just want to past the "correlation id" in the Splunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Generate a UUID and pass it as a header into the request. For any of the request that do not have this header add a filter thats checks for it and add it.
Your filter will pick such a header and can put it in thread local where MDC can pick it from. There after any logging you do will have the correlation id. When making a call to any other process/request you need to make sure you pass this id as an argument/header. And the cycle repeats.

Your thread doing the task should just be aware of this ID. Its upto you to decide how you want to pass it. Try to just separate out such concerns from your biz logic (Using Aspects or any other way you see fit) and more you can keep this under the hood easier it would be for you.

You can refer to this [example](http://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback)